# Get all derived methods of a method

Tags: c#, reflection

Given a method in `C#`, I need to find all methods in subclasses which overrides directly or indirectly that method.

For example, given the following class architecture

```cs
abstract class A { public abstract void m(); }
class B : A { public override void m(){}; }
class C : A { public override void m(){}; }
class D : C { public override void m(){}; }
class E : C { public override void m(){}; }
class F : E { public override void m(){}; }
class G : C {  }
class H : G { public override void m(){}; }
```

Then the derived methods of `C.m` would be those from the classes D, E, F, H.

I came up with the following solution that seems to work fine but find it somewhat cumbersome. I suspect there is a clever way to do that. Any thought?

```cs
    public static IEnumerable<MethodInfo> DerivedMethods(this MethodInfo mi)
    {
        return mi.DeclaringType.Assembly.GetTypes()
            .Where(klass => klass.IsSubclassOf(mi.DeclaringType))
            .Select(subclass => subclass.GetMethods(
                    BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
                .SingleOrDefault(m => m.GetBaseDefinition() == mi.GetBaseDefinition()))
            .Where(x => x != null);
    }
```

Comment: perhaps http://codereview.stackexchange.com would be better if you're just looking for someone to review code that "works fine"

Comment: @Rufus Well, you are probably right. I didn't know about that other place...

Answer (score -1):

One way to make it a little more compact is to use LINQ keywords instead.

And the `SingleOrDefault` call is a bit redundant. There can only ever be at most one override per method per class.

Also, I noticed your code only works for base *classes*. *Interfaces* work a bit different, not sure if you wanted to implement that as well?

```
public static IEnumerable<MethodInfo> DerivedMethods(this MethodInfo mi)
{
    Type baseType = mi.DeclaringType;
    IEnumerable<Type> subClasses = baseType.Assembly.GetTypes().Where((klass) => klass != baseType && baseType.IsAssignableFrom(klass));
    if (baseType.IsInterface) {
        return from klass in subClasses
               where !klass.IsInterface
               let map = klass.GetInterfaceMap(baseType)
               select map.TargetMethods[Array.IndexOf(map.InterfaceMethods, mi)];
    }
    else {
        return from klass in subClasses
               where !klass.IsAbstract // include this only if you want instantiable classes
               from m in klass.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
               where m.GetBaseDefinition() == mi.GetBaseDefinition()
               select m;
    }
}
```

If you wanted to expand the search to all Assemblies in the solution you'd change the `subClasses` to:

```
    IEnumerable<Type> subClasses = from asm in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                                   from klass in asm.GetTypes()
                                   where klass != baseType && baseType.IsAssignableFrom(klass)
                                   select klass;
```